# Asp.Net MVC weird error when filling a really big form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On a new website, I've an huge formular(meaning really big, needs at least 15-20min to finish it), that configure the whole website for one client for the next year.

It's distributed between several tabs(it's a wizard). Every time we go to the next tab, it makes a regular(non ajax) call to the server that generate the next "page". The previous informations are stored in the session(an object with a custom binder).

Everything was working fine until we test it today with all real data. Real data needs reflexion, work to find correct elements, ... And it takes times.

The problem we got is that the View receive a Model partialy empty. The session duration is set to 1440 minutes(and in IIS too). For now what I know is that I get a NullException the first time I try to access the Model into my view.

I'm checking the controller since something like 1 hour, but it's just impossible it gives a null model. If I put all those data very fast, I don't have any problem(but it's random data).

For now I did only manage to reproduce this problem on the IIS server, and I'm checking elmah logs to debug it, so it's not so easy to reproduce it.

Have you just any idea about how should I debug this? I'm a little lost here

Comment: Honestly when dealing with tab views I would save the data in a database table. You might decide that you want to separate partial entries (such as if they fill out one tab and never come back) so you could store each tabs data as XML and write code that will serialize it back into a statically typed object. Once the user has completed all of the tabs you could take the data and store it in the appropriate places throughout your database, and then delete the temp. XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the sessions wasn't having enough space I think. I resolved temporary my problem by restarting the application pool.  Still searching a solution that will not implies to changes all this code. Maybe with other mode of session states, but I need to make my models serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assume session does not offer reliable persistence. I am not sure about details but I guess it will start freeing some elements when it exceeds its memory limit.

You will be safer if you use database to store that information or you could introduce your own implementation for persisting state.

Comment: So it's possible that IIS free session informations depending of the available space? Ok, I didn't tought that was possible. Is there a way to temporary increase the allocated space for session?

Comment: I guess there is but in your scenario I think you should choose safer methods then ASP.NET session. After all it's not designed for storing critical data for long periods.

Comment: 20min is not so long period, and now I can not just change this. When the release will be done, we will for sure investigate about how to do this(and we will have one year to do it), but right now I've only a few hours to make it works. So do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to ans provided by @Ufuk
you can easily send an `ajax` request every 1 minute which would actually do nothing but by doing this the `session` wont get expired and site will continue to run in extended periods

Comment: I don't think it's timeout related, because we have set a 1440min(1 day) timeout on both IIS and web.config.